# How to disable GUI and only use terminal?

Tags: command-line, lightdm, gdm

My laptop is running very slow so I thought about disabling the GUI and some preferred me to use this command to disable GUI 
`sudo service gdm stop`
But using this command i am not abled to type anything, I mean I atleast want a terminal but the screen only shows a blinker blinking and I am not abled to type anything.
Please can someone recommend me anything else so that I can disable the GUI and enable it whenever I want.

Answer (score 0):

By stopping the GDM service `sudo service GDM stop` you are being dropped to the **Linux Virtual Console**. There are 7 of them, accessible by the keyboard shortcuts `Ctrl-Alt-F1` through `Ctrl-Alt-F7`.

My guess is the blinking cursor you see is present on the first console. When you type `Ctrl-Alt-F2` you will switch to the second console, where you'll be presented with a login prompt. Simply enter your username and password to login!

Beware though that most people would find using their computer directly from the virtual console a huge pain. Still, I believe that disabling the GUI is a *great* way to start your journey of truly learning how Linux-based systems *actually* work.

Personally, I installed the `xinit` package and got rid of GDM entirely. Whenever I need to do graphical work, I run `startx` to start the X windows server.

Comment: The ``` ctrl-alt-f2``` is not working...

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070235/enabling-virtual-consoles-in-ubuntu-18-04